# ML Kit iOS Face Detection Bug

Tags: ios, swift, face-detection, google-mlkit

I've been trying to use the [Google ML Face Detection iOS Library](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/ios)
but there is an issue with it not working with the front facing camera, it is only able to detect the faces when I use the back camera on my phone. I printed out the orientation and everything matches between front and back. It seems to work with both front and back on my iPhone X but when I test it on iPhone 11's and iPhone X max's it only works with the back camera. I am not sure what is causing this inconsistency. The code I use is below, note that all images passed into the photoVerification function are run through the fixedOrientation function first to ensure consistency:

```
 func photoVerification(image: UIImage?) {
    guard let imageFace = image else { return }
    //Enhanced Face Detection
    let options = FaceDetectorOptions()
    options.performanceMode = .accurate
    //Initialize face detector with given options
    let faceDetector = FaceDetector.faceDetector(options: options)
    // Initialize a VisionImage object with the given UIImage.
    let visionImage = VisionImage(image: imageFace)
    visionImage.orientation = imageFace.imageOrientation
    print("$$The Images Orientation is: ",imageFace.imageOrientation.rawValue)
    faceDetector.process(visionImage) { faces, error in
        guard error == nil, let faces = faces, !faces.isEmpty else {
          // [START_EXCLUDE]
          let errorString = error?.localizedDescription ?? "NO Results Possible"
            print("Error: ",errorString)
          //No face detected provide error on image
          print("No face detected!")
          self.userVerified = false
          self.addVerifiedTag(isVerified: false)
          // [END_EXCLUDE]
          return
        }

        // Faces detected
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        //Face Has been detected Offer Verified Tag to user
        print("Face detected!")
        self.userVerified = true
        self.addVerifiedTag(isVerified: true)
    }
}


func fixedOrientation(image:UIImage) -> UIImage?{
    guard image.imageOrientation != .up else{
        //Orientation is correct
        return image
    }
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else{
        //CGimage not available
        return nil
    }
    guard let colorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace, let ctx = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(image.size.width), height: Int(image.size.height), bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue) else{
        return nil
    }
    var  transform:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    
    switch image.imageOrientation {
    case .down, .downMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: image.size.height)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)
    case .left, .leftMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: 0)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2.0)
    case .right, .rightMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: image.size.height)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / -2.0)
    case .up, .upMirrored:
        break
    @unknown default:
        break
    }

    // Flip image one more time if needed to, this is to prevent flipped image
    switch image.imageOrientation {
    case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: 0)
        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
    case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.height, y: 0)
        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
    case .up, .down, .left, .right:
        break
    @unknown default:
        break
    }

    ctx.concatenate(transform)

    switch image.imageOrientation {
    case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
        ctx.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.height, height: image.size.width))
    default:
        ctx.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
        break
    }

    guard let newCGImage = ctx.makeImage() else { return nil }
    return UIImage.init(cgImage: newCGImage, scale: 1, orientation: .up)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Google ML Kit [Face Detection](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/ios) SDK in your post works for both front and back cameras on iPhone 11 (mine is running iOS 13.4 and I uses Xcode 11.6). You can check out the iOS Quickstart sample apps (in both Swift and Objective-C), which demonstrate how you can use both front and back cameras to take photos (or preview live videos) to do face detection (and other features):

https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/ios/quickstarts/vision